# DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE JOB does not working with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I've been searching some Internet before asking this question, but I've not found answer. Short question - is Oracle's job working with DBMS_OUTPUT? I want to write on console some text at given interval, but it's not working for me. For example, I want after every 3 seconds write timestamp on console.

Job - does not work.

Job + program, also does not work.

job + program + scheduler, does not work...

Could anyone give me some hints how to get it? :)

My example code:

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name =>        'some_job',
job_type =>        'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
job_action =>      'BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSTIMESTAMP); END;',
start_date =>       SYSTIMESTAMP,
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY; INTERVAL=3',
end_date =>         NULL,
enabled =>          TRUE,
comments =>        'Example job.');
end;
```

Comment: hi, each job means a session in oracle db, each session has a output buffer(console) for itself, so your problem is to catch the session and then get its output buffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each job is run in its own sessions separate to yours; your console would only be listening to the output from your session, so your job is merely speaking into the void and its output buffer is cleared before being written anywhere.

Since [DBMS_OUTPUT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036) is only really intended as a very basic debug output generator, this is not a problem. If you want to see the progress of your job in real time, here are two options to consider:

1. Insert log entries to a custom table (perhaps commit using an autonomous transaction) - or even better, use an existing logging framework like [Logger](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger).
2. Update the session using [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS003) (e.g. use `set_action` or `set_session_longops`) - this would allow you to see the current state of the job only, however.

Comment: You are right Jefferey - when I made select on USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS with name of my job, column SESSION_ID has different values for each row. 

I though, that my case is simple to do - simple, as code in my original question, but life shows that is not.. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c you can use a new feature that captures exactly the DMBS_Output:
All output like

```
dbms_output.put_line('Done');
```

Can be seen with

```
select OUTPUT from DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS -- or USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
```

See also [this excellent article here](https://connor-mcdonald.com/2016/06/27/dbms_output-and-the-scheduler/#comment-7644)